# Show that $F_p ^2$ , considered as a vector space over Fp , is a union of finitely many proper subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-fields

Show that $F_p ^2$ , considered as a vector space over Fp , is a union of finitely many proper  subspaces.
please explain what do u mean by  $F_p ^2$ before answering the qstn.  I know about $F_p$  as $Z$/p$Z$ and there are finite fields of p^n elements Also answer the qstn.

Comment: Are you following a course, a book or a set of notes? The notation should be explained somewhere in there.

Answer (score 2):

Ordered pairs $(a,b)$ of elements $a,b\in F_p$, equipeed with pointwise addition and scalar multiplication, i.e

$$c(a,b)=(ca,cb)$$
$$(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$$

for every $a,b,c,d\in F_p$.

See [ordered pairs of numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Second_example:_ordered_pairs_of_numbers). The construction is entirely similar, replacing the real numbers by $F_p$.

Comment: just like R^2 rt??

Comment: @raghu Precisely.

Comment: can u also show it as finite union

Answer (score 0):

@JackozeeHakkiuz has provided the definition of that vector space. Here's a hint for proving that it is a union of finitely many subspaces: can you see why the real plane (real two dimensional vector space) is a union of lines through the origin?